# Detecting an element being click using the onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm debugging my code in react and I have an element that isn't behaving as I expected.

`<li onClick={console.log('li element clicked')}>Hello</li>`

I simply want to detect if a particular element is clicked and I expect when I click this li element, it should log the message "li element clicked" in my console. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Please help?

---

Somehow, by using bind(this) fixes my problem, however, I don't fully understand why.

Here's the code sample:

```
export class InputQuestion extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        value: '',
    };
}

handleClick = () => {
    console.log('li 1 clicked');
}

render(){
    return (
        <Container>
            <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Hi</li>
            <li onClick={console.log('li 2 clicked')}>Hello</li>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: `this.handleClick` should be good enough. No need to bind `this` since binding occurs automatically of the `this` keyword when you use arrow functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do it as a function e.g.

```
<li onClick={() => console.log('li 2 clicked')}>Hello</li>
```

and because your `handleClick` function is an arrow function, it is already bound to `this` so you can just do:

```
<li onClick={this.handleClick}>Item 1</li>
```

Comment: is console.log not a function?

Comment: @VincentWei it is a function, but you are calling the function within the onClick. You would have to pass `console.log` without passing an argument, but that would result in the click event being passed in as the argument.

Comment: yeah, to add to what @ryandrewjohnson said (which is 100% correct), you are immediately invoking `console.log` by having `()` with a parameter, in your case 'li 2 clicked'; if you were to load the page and look at the console, you should see `li 2 clicked` without actually clicking it (with your version of the code)